# How find this matrix in an equation

Tags: matrices

> Let $x$ is give numbers.and define  the matrix $A$ such
>   $$A^T\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&x\\
> x&1
> \end{bmatrix}\cdot A=1$$
>
> this book say it is clear have
>   $$A=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+x)}}\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}$$

I think this not true,let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}$$
then we have
$$A^T\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1&x\\
x&1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot A=\binom{a+bx}{b+ax}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}=a^2+b^2+2abx=1$$

First which is wrong?

why is "clear" can you explain? Thank you,If not it is clear,can you solve this equation

Comment: Is there some additional condition that means that $A = (1\ \ 0)^T$ doesn't work?

Comment: It seems like the given answer does work and is the only answer such that $a = b$. Is that necessary for some reason? Or is it just the case that the book is trying to give *a* solution rather than *the* solution?

Comment: oh,maybe this book is not true, if $a=b$ is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true and clear

if you let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}$$
then we have
$$A^T\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
1&x\\
x&1
\end{bmatrix}\cdot A=\binom{a+bx}{b+ax}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}=a^2+b^2+2abx=1$$

the book assumed a case where $a=b$.

This will then give $a^2+a^2+2a^2x=1$ and solving for a gives:
$$a=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+x)}}$$
Therefore we will have
$$A=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+x)}}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

Is the above relation meant to be true for all real x? Because otherwise, there is some problem. For example, take x=0 and see that **a** = (1,0)' satisfies the above relation, although **a** is not of the above form.

Comment: In fact, I just realized from Ben's comment that (1,0)' anyway works, whether or not the relation is required to be true for all x!

Comment: The expression the book gave is true